mounting owncloud in nginx and fedora
im trying to install a owncloud in a nginx server. So far i managed somehow to actually start the installation of owncloud but i cant make it further. i got this error and i have no idea what it means

[error] 70187#70187: *13 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/html/owncloud/config/config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/owncloud/lib/private/Config.php on line 239PHP message: PHP Warning:  flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in /var/www/html/owncloud/lib/private/Config.php on line 249PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/owncloud/data/crash-2024-06-06.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/owncloud/lib/kernel.php on line 1038PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/owncloud/data/crash-2024-06-06.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/owncloud/lib/kernel.php on line 1038" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "localhost"

My nginx.conf file is this one
user apache;

http{
        types_hash_max_size 4096;
        include mime.types;
        server{
                listen 80;
                root /var/www/html/owncloud;
                index index.php;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        autoindex on;
                        include fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                                }
        }
}
events{}

i tried changing users and permisions but i have no idea what this error means

i fixed it with keeping the owner as root and giving permision to all with chmodchmod -R 777 owncloud

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
